# What is the oldest piece of visual media involving computerized dating services?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, trope

[TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/OlderThanTheyThink/Technology) mentions the history of digital dating services, and then notes that there's media from before the 1990s about it.

> Using computers as dating services did not start with the rise of the internet in The '90s. It has been around since 1941, and originally used paper forms that were input into a computer. There were several romantic comedy movies and TV episodes made about computer dating services.

I found some of them using [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=computer-dating&ref_=fn_al_kw_1&sort=release_date,asc&mode=detail&page=1), but its earliest are from 1967, using a keyword search at least.

Do we know the first depiction of such a trope?

Comment: Edited to align title with text and remove the "list" request implied by the original text.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Interesting, I didn't pick up that implication, but thanks!

Comment: [This article](https://www.businessinsider.com/first-online-dating-site-2011-7) seems to think it actually began in 1965.  There were several movies and TV shows that revolve around computer dating in the late 60's, so I'm not sure about that 1941 date.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Oh, this even only starts in 1959... hmm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_online_dating_services

Answer (score 3):

Computer dating began in 1964 in the UK with the St James Computer Dating Service.  It hit the US shores a year later with the company [Operation Match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Match).  Prior to this, some companies did attempt to find matches using questionnaires, but they were manually compared versus being fed into a computer via punchcard.

There was a movie named [*Office Love-In* (1968)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063378/) in which the plot was about a secretary who gets matched with her boss.

There was also an episode of Green acres called [*The Computer Age* (1967)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0592766/fullcredits) where their neighbor Ralph (a woman) joins a computer dating service to meet a husband.  That same year there was an episode of [*The Danny Kaye Show* (1967)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1447714/?ref_=kw_li_tt) where Danny's character joins a computer dating service.